# How to get the TextView close to the EditText in ScrollView + Relative Layout

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-layout

I want the "tv_email_address" (Email address) TextView to be right on the top of the "et_email_address" EditText.

I'm using ScrollView and Relative Layout.

But without adding margin or padding on top/bottom it leaves an awful lot of space between them.

Why does it do this? How can I get rid of that unwanted space between them?

Here's an image of it of how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpvKF.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".EnterCredentials"
android:background="@color/black">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_create_account_header"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/arrow_left"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_email_address"
    android:text="@string/create_an_account"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/museo_sans_300"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/arrow_left"
    android:background="@drawable/arrow_left"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
         />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/white_line"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/arrow_left"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.1dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_email_address"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/white_line"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/et_email_address"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_create_account_header"
    android:text="Email address"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:paddingStart="40dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/museo_sans_300"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_email_address"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_email_address"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/iv_email_exists"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/museo_sans_300"
    android:textSize="20dp"

    />
```

Comment: in et_email_address remove app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/iv_email_exists"

Comment: Thanks JalalKun that actually did the job!
I have this iv_email_exists that is by default gone.

Comment: that's great, i'm learn too